# Trigger rebalance of a consumer group

Tags: spring-kafka

Is there a way to manually trigger a rebalance without restarting a spring kafka container (and before the metadata max age)? Since Kafka 2.6, there is enforceRebalance() to trigger the rebalance from the consumer API but it is private in the spring kafka containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `Consumer` as a parameter to the listener and call `enforceRabalance()` on it and the rebalance will occur on the next poll.

If the container is idle, you can set an `idleEventInterval` and the consumer is available in the `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#idle-containers

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#event-consumption

Comment: Thanks Gary. Is it safe to call consumer.subscribe (newTopic) and then enforceRebalance() to update the current consumer's topic list to avoid restarting the container? Then, the concurrent listener will sometimes be restarted with the updated topic list to rebalance topics among CMLC consumers.

Comment: It's certainly not designed to be used that way; according to the javadocs `Topic subscriptions are not incremental.` which means you would have to re-subscribe to all topics, you would also disconnect the container's rebalance listener which could cause undesirable side effects. I would expect any `subscribe` operation to cause a rebalance without the need to force one, but I wouldn't recommend you do this. If you want to add a topic at runtime, I suggest you open a new feature request issue (and contributions are welcome).

Comment: I've tested the creation of new containers at runtime and it's enough fast for what we need. Thanks for your help.